# Migrating news feeds from Windows Live to?

Tags: windows-vista, feed, windows-live-mail

I am trying to migrate my newsfeeds from the Vista Windows Live Mail program to a web based reader, because I would like to get my newsfeeds and RSS in one place. I travel alot and now my email is thru WLM, which is inconvenient away from that Desktop.

My question is two-fold: what would be the best way to MOVE my currently saved feeds, and their urls to another reader, and what is the best Reader to use, when I eventually MOVE all my emails to the web?

Answer (score 1):

> what is the best Reader to use, when I eventually MOVE all my emails to the web?

I use [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader) and think it is fantastic.

Comment: Google reader doesn't have a cosmetic interface though.

Comment: What do you mean by "cosmetic interface"?

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend Google Reader, it certinly has the largest user base, and is probably the most  stable. I also like the interface, it is quick and has lots of key bindings.

It shouldn't be that hard to transition to Google Reader:

1. Export an OPML file from IE7 using "import / export" this will read your windows live mail feed list.
2. Import the OPML file into Google Reader.

This process is simple enough that you could just import your feeds into Google Reader and see if you like it.

There are also several mobile / desktop clients that sync with google reader.

- iphone: [ByLine](http://www.phantomfish.com/byline.html), [NetNewsWire 2.0](http://www.newsgator.com/Individuals/NetNewsWireiPhone/Default.aspx)
- Windows: [FeedDemon 3.0](http://www.feeddemon.com/)
- mac: [NetNewsWire](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/internet_utilities/netnewswire.html), [Eventbox](http://thecosmicmachine.com/)